# Multiple threads not inserting everything into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, multithreading, jakarta-ee

Excuse any wrong practices as I am very new to threading. I have a program that calls my api and gets data back in json format. Each request returns a row of data in json format. All together I need to retrieve about 2,000,000 rows a day which means 2,000,000 requests (I understand that this is bad design, but the system was not designed for this purpose it is just what I need to do for the next couple of weeks). When I tried running it on a single thread I was processing about 200 requests a minute which is much too slow. As a result I created 12 threads and I was processing 5500 rows a minutes which was a great improvement. The problem was only about on average 90% of the rows were inserted into the database as I ran it a few times to make sure. Before each insert printed to a file each URL which was sent and then I checked to see if each insert statement was successful (returned 1 when executed ) and it all seems fine. Every time I run it it inserts about 90% but it does varies and it has never been a consistent number. Am I doing something wrong inside my java code? Essentially the code starts in main by creating 12 threads. Each thread's creates a run method which calls a new instance of MySQLPopulateHistData and passes a start and end integer which are used in the insert statement for ranges. I have done many system.out.println type testing and can see all the threads do start and all the 12 instances (one instance for each thread) called are executing? Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

MAIN:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class MainClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

             //create a pool of threads

             Thread[] threads = new Thread[12];

            //  submit jobs to be executing by the pool



             for (int i = 0; i <12; i++) {

            threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                     try {

                              new MySQLPopulateHistData(RangeClass.IdStart, RangeClass.IdEnd);

                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                             //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                 });
                 threads[i].start();
                 Thread.sleep(1000);

                    RangeClass.IdStart = RangeClass.IdEnd + 1;  
                    RangeClass.IdEnd = RangeClass.IdEnd + 170000;
             }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

MyDataSourceFactory.class

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;



    public class MyDataSourceFactory {

        static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_schema";
        static String userName = "root"; 
        static String password = "password";


        public synchronized static DataSource getMySQLDataSource() {


            MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;

            mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();

            mysqlDS.setURL(url);

            mysqlDS.setUser(userName);

            mysqlDS.setPassword(password);

            return mysqlDS;

        }    

    }
```

MySQLPopulateHistData.class

```
public class MySQLPopulateHistData {

        public MySQLPopulateHistData(int s, int e ) throws IOException, Throwable{

            getHistory(s,e);


        }
            public synchronized void getHistory(int start, int end){


                DataSource ds = MyDataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();


                Connection con = null;
                Connection con2 = null;

                Statement stmt = null;
                Statement stmt2 = null;

                ResultSet rs = null;


                try {

                    con = ds.getConnection();
                    con2 = ds.getConnection();

                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    stmt2 = con.createStatement();

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT s FROM sp_t where s_id BETWEEN "+ start +" AND "+  end + " ORDER BY s;");


                    String s = "";


                    while(rs.next()){

                         s = rs.getString("s");


                        if( s == ""){

                        }
                        else{

                        try{


                            URL fullUrl = new URL(//My Url to my api with password with start and end range);


                        InputStream is = fullUrl.openStream();
                        String jsonStr = getStringFromInputStream(is);


                          JSONObject j = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                            JSONArray arr = j.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("quote");


                            for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                String symbol = obj.getString("s");


                            stmt2.executeUpdate("INSERT into sp2_t(s) VALUES ('"+ s +"') BETWEEN "+start+" AND "+ end +";");


                            }


                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                        }


                            }
                            s = "";

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }finally{

                        try {

                            if(rs != null) rs.close();

                            if(stmt != null) stmt.close();

                            if(con != null) con.close();



                            if(stmt2 != null) stmt.close();

                            if(con2 != null) con.close();



                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                }

            }



}
```

**UPDATE:**

So I put:

```
(if s.equals("")){
System.out.println("EMPTY");
}
```

and it never printed out EMPTY. After the JSON requests gets converted to the JSONArray I added:

```
if(arr.length()>0){
StaticClassHolder.cntResponses++;
}
```

This is just a static variable in another class that gets incremented everytime there is a valid JSON response. It equalled to the exact right amount it was supposed to be. So it seems as if the URL gets all the responses properly, parses them properly, but is not INSERTING them properly into the database? I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar  issue while inserting records in Oracle. Since I didn't find any concrete solution. I tried with single thread and all went fine.

Answer (score -1):

There are several reasons why this does not work:

- A normal computer can only handle about 4-8 threads in total per cpu. As the system uses some of thise threads you would only be able to run some threads at the same time. The computer handles this by pausing some threads then running another thread.
- If you try to send several queries through the socket to the mysql server at the same time chanses are that some of the requests will not work and you lose some of your data.

As for now I do not have any solution for faster updates of the table.

Comment: I have a 6 core processor (12 threads) and when I tried with 12 threads   I had the same issue. Is there a way to send a thread's mysql request on another socket?

Comment: I don't know how the mysql server will handle multiple requests at the same time. I would think they have coded for this. If so you have to start a new instance that connects to the mysql server and give one such instance to each of the threads. With other words let each thread create it's own instance of a class that connects to the mysql server

Comment: Is that now what I am already doing in my code by calling the MyDataSourceFactory class inside of MySQLPopulateHistData?

Comment: Uhm, yeah, everything looks correct from what I can see. Either a problem I can't find or that the mysql database actually can't handle that many requests. Sorry I couldn't help you out

Comment: I set my mysql max connection to 2000 to be safe and the problem still persisted. Thanks though!